# what are the easiest way to create a data validation in each records in a table?

Tags: sql, bash, oracle11g, sh, oracle-sqldeveloper

my logic on my recent project is that when user input a information thru csv , my CTL file will retrieved the data from csv to the temporary table and I want to create a **data validation script** to **validate** each data records in temporary table before transferring it to the main table.

Comment: How is this question related to `bash`, or to `sh`? If I understand you correctly, you are searching for a PL/SQL solution; and **if** a shell is involved, please specify whether you mean bash or sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would likely create a procedure which grabs chunks of the temp table, checks them and then inserts them into the base table.  Something like:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE lt_toValidate IS TABLE OF temp_table%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  
  lc_fetchLimit CONSTANT INTEGER := 5000;
  l_tToVal lt_toValidate;
  
  CURSOR c_toVal IS
    SELECT *
    FROM temp_table;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_toVal;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_toVal
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tToVal
    LIMIT lc_fetchLimit;
    
    EXIT WHEN l_tToVal.COUNT = 0;
    
    FOR i IN 1..l_tToVal.COUNT LOOP
      IF NOT(is_record_valid()) THEN
        l_tToVal.DELETE(i);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    
    FORALL i IN INDICES OF l_tToVal
      INSERT INTO base_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (l_tToVal(i).col1, l_tToVal(i).col2, l_tToVal(i).col3);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You just need to replace `is_record_valid()` with whatever you are using to determine validity and obviously replace with your table and columns names.

Comment: HI , just a asking what is the purpose of "INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER" on line 2 ?

Comment: @BROX It is just using an associative array instead of a nested table. I always use this reference for collections ([Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005))

Comment: @brox in this case, I could have just left that clause out and used a nested table.  It is just my goto.